# Display multiple database fields into a PHP table loop

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this for around 4 hours now...
What I'm trying to establish is pretty simple, I have a news table, I want to display the title of the news, the content, and a read more link, I know how to loop through a table and force , but this won't work in my case, the table should look like this in the end:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>header one</td>
    <td>header 2</td>
    <td>header 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text one</td>
    <td>text two</td>
    <td>text 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>read more</td>
    <td>read more </td>
    <td>read more</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I have so far in my php is a code that will generate the rows and columns, but I want them to be distributed just like the sample table above in order not to mess the alignment of the text and the read more link ...
Here's my php code :

```
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <?php while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
                        <?php $style++ ?>
                            <td width="33%" valign="top">

                                <h6><?php echo $record['title'] ?></h6>
                                <div class="service-sum"><?php echo $record['content'] ?></div>
                                <div class="findout"><a href="services-details.php?<?php echo $record['url'] ?>/<?php echo $record['num'] ?>">> find out more</a></div>
                            </td>

            <?php if ($style == 3): ?>
                </tr>
                    <?php $style = 0; ?> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="height:30px;"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
            <?php endif ?>

        <?php endwhile ?>
```

This one is working fine, but i'm displaying the title and the content and the read more link in one column, these should be distributed into 3 for design purposes...
Any help would be much appreciated, I looked all over the net and I can't find a solution for that!

Answer (score 0):

try using this alignment. The design is almost same as yours.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>header one</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>text one</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>read more</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td>header 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>text 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>read more</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>header 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>read more</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if there are only 3 records, the following should be fine. if there are more, some changes should be made. Please check your php code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <td> 
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $record['title'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td height = "30px;"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $record['content'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="services-details.php?<?php echo $record['url'] ?>/<?php echo $record['num'] ?>">> find out more</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
And yeah I wish there was only 3 records, many ways would've worked, but it's not the case, sometimes there will be 2 or 3 records, other times 9 records, it depends :)

Thanks!